# supervisor not running inside container

Tags: python, docker, supervisord

Supervisord not running after container startup, I can't find whats wrong with my settings.
I have checked by entering bash to container, supervisor status not running. And in docker logs I can't see supervisord running logs. But if enter container bash, and start manually everything works perfect.

The big problem is that I can't see any errors.

My dockerfile:

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.5-buster as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/dodo

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev python3-dev \
    libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
    libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev \
    supervisor

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/dodo/wheels -r requirements.txt

#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.5-buster

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/dodo/webapp
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

# create the app user
RUN groupadd -r app && useradd -r -g app app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/dodo/webapp
ENV APP_HOME=/home/dodo/webapp/web
ENV ALFACENTER=/media/alfacenter
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev supervisor
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/dodo/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/dodo/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app users
# USER app

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

supervisord.conf file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:djangoWatcher]
command=/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /home/dodo/webapp/web/djangoWatcherRun.py
directory=/home/dodo/webapp/web
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisord.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisord.out.log
user=app
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./webapp
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        # build: ./webapp
        tty: true
        command: gunicorn --workers=2 --threads=4 main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - /media/ftp/:/media/alfacenter/
            - static_volume:/home/dodo/webapp/web/staticfiles
        expose:
            - 8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.prod
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/home/dodo/webapp/web/staticfiles
        depends_on:
            - web
volumes:
    static_volume:
```

Comment: You are overriding your command in your docker-compose file to run `gunicorn` inside container. To verify this you can use `docker inspect <container-id>` to see what is the value of CMD and entrypoint is.

Comment: Docker isn't very cooperative when it comes to running supervisors. What are you actually hoping to accomplish with this arrangement? Perhaps running Docker itself with `--restart-automatically` would make more sense?

Comment: Can you remove the entire supervisord setup, and move the `command:` line from the `docker-compose.yml` to be the standard `CMD` your image runs instead?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're starting the container with Compose, the issue is `command: gunicorn --workers=2 --threads=4 main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000` I suspect, you've set a different overriding startup command.

Couple of unrelated issues I noticed:

1. You're installing `python3-dev` package with apt. You shouldn't do that: the official `python` image already has Python and Python development headers preinstalled, so you're ending up with two versions of Python which can break things.
2. `RUN chown` makes your image bigger, since it basically copies all those files again. Do `COPY --chown=app:app . $APP_HOME` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I would say use ENTRYPOINT docker command instead of using CMD to run your supervisord in docker file will solve the issue.

Comment: This shouldn't be a significant difference; either way Docker will run only a single command in the container.  (But with this particular `docker-compose.yml` file, it will pass the `gunicorn` command as additional arguments to `supervisord`, which probably isn't what you want either.)